# Only show user_id and username after log in in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a login and registration system in codeignitor.
This is my controller -

```
 function index()
 {
     if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
     {
         $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
         //$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
         $data = array(
              'user_id'=>$session_data['user_id'],
              'username'=>$session_data['username'],
              'firstname'=>$session_data['firstname'],
              'lastname'=>$session_data['lastname']
         );
         $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
     }
     else
     {
         //If no session, redirect to login page
        redirect('login', 'refresh');
     }
 }
```

this code only show me the user_id and username. but not showing the firstname and lastname. Please help me ...

Comment: Please let us see how did you set your session?

Comment: Here another code from my controller -

Comment: if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'user_id' => $row->user_id,
         'username' => $row->username
       );
       $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
     }
     return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
     return false;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have set your session like this,

```
$data = array(
    'user_id'=>id,
    'username'=>"name",
    'logged_in'=>1,
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

To access values from session,

```
$this->session->userdata("name of session variable");
```

In your case,

```
$this->session->userdata("user_id");// for user id
$this->session->userdata("user_name");// for user name
```

Comment: can you tell me why I can't see the other records like firstname, lastname etc. only showing user id and username. Well, I have copy the login system and implement it into my It was only contains with user id, username and password. Than I created the registration form with two more fields firstname and lastname and also created new row in table for this. The new record with I built with my own can not get...

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result) { 
    $sess_array = array(); 

    foreach($result as $row) { 
        $sess_array = array( 
                          'user_id' => $row->user_id, 
                          'username' => $row->username 
                      ); 
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array); 
    } 

    return TRUE;

} else {

    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password'); 
    return false; 

}
```

In your above given code I can't find the `firstname` in session setting. But you are trying to get `firstname` then how will the code provide you the `firstname`.